# How do I use MoreLikeThis function on Solr to find similar documents to a text file?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, morelikethis

I am trying to use solr to do the following:

Read some text from a txt file, and use MoreLikeThis on the text to find similar documents to that text. How can I do this with Solr?

From what I know so far I think I have to use content stream, but I do not know how to configure it...

Answer (score 1):

If you were forming a MoreLikeThisQuery from a document stored in the index, it would have formed the query by retrieving the TermVector info from the Index.

Since you are willing to find documents similar to a text file you have, you've got to iterate the text file and form the BooleanQuery, with the terms in the text file, the way you want to match.

The above is true for Lucene, and I believe it's the same for Solr as well, considering that the MoreLikeThisQuery works based on TermVector info.